# Adding a threshold for closing/reopening duplicate question to limit "robo-reviewers"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

We all know that there are a lot of users who *blindly* click on buttons inside the different queues in order to simply get higher stats and earn badges. We have some way to prevent this using audits and bans, but in some cases, we can do nothing.

My concern will be closing/reopening question when it's a duplicate (especially reopening)

Back when it needed 5 votes to close or reopen, *blind votes* were no issue because it was very rare that 4 users (I am considering the fact that the OP is voting to reopen his own question) clicked the button without paying attention. I could easily identify these cases and close the question again by pinging another gold user. I faced this probably 10 times in more than 2000 questions I have closed with the 5 close vote requirement.

### "Wait, how can you make sure that the votes are wrong and users aren't doing the review correctly? Maybe *your* close vote is the bad one!"

I consider 4 factors:

1. The duplicate is a perfect one from my perspective.
2. After closing the question there is no edit made by the OP to explain why it's not a duplicate (or we can find the common edit: "No it's not a duplicate .. please reopen!").
3. The users reopening the question have 0 activity in the concerned tag. 0 answers, 0 votes, etc.
4. When I ping another gold user to review the question, he agrees with me and the question gets closed again.

Following these guidelines, I am sure that reopen-votes on questions I closed are wrong and users blindly voted the question.

---

Now with only 3 votes needed, it becomes an issue and the above will be more recurrent because it's easier to have 2 *blind votes* in order to reopen the question. I am starting to face this more often than before that's why I think we need to consider a way to prevent this or at least to limit it.

My idea is to prevent 3. (in my above list) from happening by adding a threshold related to the tag score. For example: "You have to have a score of 10 on the CSS tag in order to vote to close/reopen a CSS question as duplicate".

Something similar to how we protect questions when using the minimum of 10 Rep.

Considering the fact that we need 3000 Rep to be able to close/reopen question, I think anyone active in any tag will for sure have at least 10 as a tag score. With this, we can be sure that only relevant users can judge duplicate questions and we limit the *blind votes*.

---

To be clear, I am not talking about gold users reopening/closing questions or any other user doing the same. I am only concerned about users doing this using the queue and when there is a **clear evidence** that the votes are wrong and also a **clear evidence** that they have 0 activity in the concerned tag. Any other case is out of the scope of this discussion.

---

I think such a feature can be helpful on a large scale. The CSS tag is not the most active one (compared with Java, C, C++, Python) so if this is bothering me I guess it's happening in the other tags as well. Probably even more often than what I have noticed after lowering the number of required votes to only 3.

The tag score of 10 is only an example. It can be 5, 20, 30 or maybe we consider the number of answers. Any metric that can help us identify a user having a *minimum activity* in the concerned tag.

Comment: Would requirement to have 3 reopen votes besides the question owner help? I would also expand that requirement to all closed questions regardless of close reason. I have seen totally off topic questions with 2 reopen votes...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar maybe it can reduce the *bad* reopening but it will not prevent the spammer. I want a way to stop them even if at the end their action are useless and the question remain closed

Comment: *I would also expand that requirement to all closed questions regardless of close reason* --> I thought to include this but not easy in this case to identify a clear way to avoid it since we don't necessarely need domain knowledge to handle some off topic questions.

Comment: As long as this restriction only exists *inside* the review queue, I think it's a great idea. It could simply be implemented as a forced tag filter.

Comment: @KevinB yes, only inside the queue because I don't think a user will grab random questions outside the queue in order to click reopen and win nothing.

Comment: I edited some parts to make them more clear. Fell free to roll back if you feel like they don't achieve that goal!