# Why has this question been re-opened?

Tags: discussion

[Here question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234653) was closed because it too broad since precise information is needed to solve the problem.

Some users who dedicate ourselves to the [pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyqt) and [pyqt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyqt5), point out that we need that additional information and explain it clearly in the comments but the OP only rewrote its publication without giving the necessary information.

It seems that that was enough for users who have privileges to vote to reopen questions to give their vote by asking a question that is not accurate to be reopened, but reviewing the tags that these users are dedicated to, I noticed that none before asked or I answered post right of PyQt so I can presume that they have not understood the necessary requirements to be able to solve the question.

So my question is: Is reopening correct?

Comment: two votes from https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/25369601

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393400/8620333 .. we really need more restriction on the queue to avoid *blind* votes since now we need only 2 votes (in addition to the OP one) to reopen a question

Comment: With only 3 close or reopen votes needed, you'll get errors more often now.